# Installing APK file causes the screen to just flash and returns to previous page

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, installation

I use Micromax Bolt Q324. The problem is that no apps get installed, its not getting into recovery mode or safe mode. I tried Factory Reset but it's also not working. When I open Apps for app info or try to install any *APK* file the screen just flashes and returns to previous page.Even it does not boots into recovery or safe mode.I HV used device just for 6 months.its has android KitKat is and its non rooted.it has still its original ROM and ram is about 512 mb.

Comment: When asking a question, provide related information such as Phone, Operation system version, (and even phone age)... What you describe sounds like damaged memory, or even faulty control application. Is the stock Google Play Store app being used or a custom one? Is the device over 4 years old (with intense usage?), is the device original? How long since a system format/cleanse?

Comment: I HV added extra information. Pks help me now.plsssssss

Comment: Can you confirm if your Android system was updated with the "OtA (Over the Air") network, and if so, can you confirm what programs werer updated along? Finally, as a precaution, disable "Network Data (GSM)", then connect your device with a Local trusted netowrk (WiFi), then uninstall the applications that are not behaving as expected, and use the browser to reach the `Play.Google` and request those aplications for new install. When completed, shutdown the device, count to 15, then start it again

Answer (score 0):

Your google play library become unstable.. Please uninstall your google account and or reset the account may be helpful.

Or you can also try to update the google play service from play store , but please uninstall the previous one if that is already installed.